# Converting RTF to PDF using python?

Tags: python, pdf, canvas, pywin32, rtf

I need to convert RTF to PDF using Python. If the RTF file include any image. my VM doesn't have Word Application.

I tried

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader as rtf_reader
import pyth.plugins.plaintext.writer as plaintext_writer

def convert_rtf_to_pdf(rtf_file, pdf_file):
  # Read the RTF file
  with open(rtf_file, 'rb') as file:
    doc = rtf_reader.Rtf15Reader.read(file)

  # Convert RTF to plain text
  plain_text = plaintext_writer.PlainTextWriter.write(doc).getvalue()

  # Create a PDF file
  c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_file)
  c.drawString(100, 750, plain_text)
  c.save()
# Usage
rtf_file = "/file.rtf"
pdf_file = "/file.pdf"
convert_rtf_to_pdf(rtf_file, pdf_file)
```

that code but that code not working if RTF file include any image inside.
then I tried

```
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(RtfFilePath)
doc.SaveAs(saveDocxPath, FileFormat=16)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

that code but i don't have word application in my VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pypandoc library in python,

```
import pypandoc

def convert_rtf_to_pdf(input_rtf, output_pdf):
    pypandoc.convert_file(input_rtf, 'pdf', outputfile=output_pdf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_rtf_path = "Path to your RTF File"
    output_pdf_path = "path to your pdf file output with name /output.pdf"

    convert_rtf_to_pdf(input_rtf_path, output_pdf_path)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spire.Doc for Python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/doc-for-python.html) library can convert RTF files with images to PDF without the need for installing the MS Word application on the system.

```
pip install Spire.Doc
```

Here is an example that converts an RTF file to PDF:

```
from spire.doc import Document, FileFormat

# Create a Document instance
doc = Document()
# Load a RTF document
doc.LoadFromFile("Test.rtf", FileFormat.Rtf)
# Save it to a PDF
doc.SaveToFile("RtfToPdf.pdf", FileFormat.PDF)
doc.Close()
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops this library.